# Rails 4: modeling a Student "Career" item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

So I have a `Student` model, and I am trying to design a page on my app that will display the full-time/internship job offers of all students in a table. I want the rows of the table to have:

- Student Name
- Company
- Group (within company)
- Location

Furthermore, I want logical horizontal divisions of the table -- I want the table first and foremost to be sorted by `year`, and within each year, I want it sorted by the type of job offer (either `full-time` or `internship`). Thus, theoretically, the `JobOffer` model that I want to make would have the six attributes listed above.

**My question:** What is the best logical way to actually implement this? I'm thinking of making my `Student` model `has_many` `JobOffer`'s, and then using `validates_inclusion_of` to limit the values of the attribute `job_type` to "internship" and "full_time" in the `JobOffer` model. The student would then be able to create a new JobOffer for themselves; I would then collate all of the JobOffer items together for the JobOffer index page, where the table would be created.

Is there a better or more logical way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) & will treat `JobOffer` as a join model:

---

**Models**

```
#app/models/student.rb
Class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :job_offers, class_name: "JobOffer"
    has_many :jobs, class_name: "Job", through: :job_offers
end

#app/models/job.rb
Class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company

    has_many :job_offers, class_name: "JobOffer"
    has_many :students, class_name: "Student", through: :offers
end

#app/models/job_offer.rb
Class JobOffer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :job
end
```

This will allow you to do this:

```
@student.job_offers # -> list of job offers
@student.jobs # -> applied jobs

@job.job_offers # -> list of offers from join model
@job.students # -> list of student who have applied for a job
```

---

**Schemas**

```
students
id | name | email | etc | etc | created_at | updated_at

jobs 
id | company_id | name | type | information | group | location | created_at | updated_at

job_offers
id | student_id | job_id | extra | vars | created_at | updated_at
```

---

**Controllers**

```
#app/controllers/job_offers_controller.rb
def new
    @job_offer = JobOffer.new
end

def create
    @job_offer = JobOffer.new(job_offer_params)
    @job_offer.save
end

private
def job_offer_params
    params.require(:job_offer).permit(:extra, :vars).merge(student_id: current_user.id, job_id: params[:id])
end


#app/controllers/students_controller.rb
def profile
    @student = Student.find(current_user.id)
    @job_offers = @student.job_offers
    @jobs = @student.jobs
end
```

---

**Views**

```
#app/views/job_offers/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @job_offer do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :extra_var_1 %>
    <%= f.text_field :extra_var_2 %>

    # -> student_id & job_id appended automatically
<% end %>
```

---

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :jobs do
    resources :job_offers, as: 'offers'
end
```

This will give you the routes: `/jobs/1/offers/new`

---

**Notes**

- **Student Name**

  Can be called from:

  `@job.students.each do |student| 
    student.name
  end`

  or

  `@student_names = @job.students.map(&:name) #-> ["Joe", "Mary", "Henry"]`
- **Company**

  `Job` belongs to `company` (company `has_many :jobs`)
- **Group (within company)**
  `Company` `has_many :groups`
- **Location**

  `@company = Company.find(params[:id])` `@company.location`